# Slide toggle with delay

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, slideup

I have a navigation with a slide up effect on the links, which once clicked, the page slides up from the bottom, while the main page called #portfolio slides down, once opened, if the user clicks the same link again I want the page to slide down.

what i'm trying to accomplish is that if once one of the 2 panels, #aboutpage and #contactpage is open while I click on the other one, for example if #aboutpage is open, and I click on the link for #contactpage, I want the about page to slide down, once down the #contactpage slides up. I have tried a dozen times with a dozen different methods and I can't seem to get it to work.

http://maximsiebert.com/unamed/Untitled-1.html

```
    $('.about').click(function() {
    if (!$('#aboutpage').is(":visible")) {
    $('#aboutpage') .slideToggle(1000)
    $('#portfolio') .slideToggle(1000)
    }
else if ($(('#contactpage').css('display') == "block")) {
    $('#contactpage') .slideToggle(1000)
    $('#aboutpage') .delay(1000).slidetoggle(1000)
}else {
    $('#portfolio').slideDown(1000);
     $('#aboutpage').slideUp(1000);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try once more.  Instead of using `slideToggle`, slide *all* of them up, then slide the current one down, but only if it wasn't visible to begin with:

```
$('.about').click(function() {
    var wasVisible = $("#aboutpage").is(":visible");
    $("#aboutpage").slideUp();
    $("#portfolio").slideUp();
    $("#contactpage").slideUp();
    if (!wasVisible) {
        $('#aboutpage').slideDown(1000)
    }
}
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rFn5v/3/).